# Scrapy Xpath for slightly changing pages

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

I am trying to scrape the information of some job adverts from www.upwork.com

Most of it can be scraped by simple Xpath, but due to the fact
that some pages have extra items (Country of client, Client amount hired etc...) or are a little different (fixed rate jobs which adds a jobprice item)

This breaks the Xpath of the items.

The items do not have descriptive class names you can use as you can see in the source code of the page.

Fixed rate job with many details about the client
https://www.upwork.com/job/Education-portal-development_~0151e2b32662a05e13/

hourly job with less detail of the client:
https://www.upwork.com/job/Create-countdown-timer-which-resets-every-night_~01d2dad2d68abd7b8d/

Some examples of the items and xpath:

```
l.add_xpath('clientactivehires', '//*[@id="layout"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/p[5]/span/text()', re = '(\d*) Active')
l.add_xpath('fixedratevariable', '//*[@id="layout"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/p/strong/text()')
l.add_xpath('fixedrate', '//*[@id="layout"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/p/strong/text()')
l.add_xpath('hired', '//*[@id="layout"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p[3]/span/text()', re = '(\d*)')
l.add_xpath('interviewing', '//*[@id="layout"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/p[3]/text()', re = '(\d*)')
l.add_xpath('jobdescription', '//*[@id="layout"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/p/text()')
```

I tried a lot of things but with xpath I can not get it to work, it works on 1 page but is not reliably working on others.

What can I do to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I would rely on the "About the Client" text instead getting all of the following `p` siblings:

```
$ scrapy shell https://www.upwork.com/job/Education-portal-development_~0151e2b32662a05e13/

>>> for item in response.xpath("//p[strong = 'About the Client']/following-sibling::p"):
...     print(" ".join(map(unicode.strip, item.xpath(".//text()").extract())))
... 
 India  Bangalore
            07:28 PM 
 3
        Jobs Posted   0% Hire Rate,
        1 Open Job
```

You would might need to improve the logic and group this additional information.